# trying to match keyword in a string that in the form of a sentence

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried two different way to search this string and match it to the Appendixkeywords string. I have tried using `Array.Exists` and  `Array.IndexOf` but both are not finding the Appendixkeywords. Any help would be great.

the code:

```csharp
public static void Main()
{
    var Appendixkeywords = new[]
    {
        "appendix h: biosimilars"
    };
    
    string source = "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff <a href=\"http://www.cnn.com\">Appendix H: Biosimilars</a> gg hh ii jj";
    string sourceb = "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff Appendix H: Biosimilars gg hh ii jj";
    
    bool b = Array.Exists(Appendixkeywords, element => element == source.ToLower());
    
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    
    int pos = Array.IndexOf(Appendixkeywords, source.ToLower());
    
    Console.WriteLine(pos);
    
    int pos1 = Array.IndexOf(Appendixkeywords, sourceb.ToLower());
    
    Console.WriteLine(pos1);
}
```

actual output:

```
False
-1
-1
```

expected output:

```
True
<some index other than -1>
<some index other than -1>
```

working sample

https://dotnetfiddle.net/QIXFDn

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  It's also not clear to me what problem you're describing or what this code is meant to do.  Are you trying to find which index *of the array* matches the string?  Because none of those strings are in the array.  Are you trying to find the index *in the string* of the single value within the array?  What if the array has multiple values?  Generally if you can articulate the specific logic of what you're trying to do, that description will very closely match the code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to check whether your `source` string contains any of the strings specified in your `Appendixkeywords` array. Additionally I assume you want to achieve a case insensitive comparison.

```csharp
bool foundAnyAppendixWord = Appendixkeywords
    .Any(word => source
        .Contains(word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You could (and maybe even should) turn this easily into a reusable method

```csharp
static bool ContainsAnySearchWord(string[] searchWords, string target)
{
    return searchWords.Any(word => target
         .Contains(word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}

// ...

bool foundAnyAppendixWord = ContainsAnySearchWord(Appendixkeywords, source);
```

#### .NET Framework (and older) versions:

```csharp
static bool ContainsAnySearchWord(string[] searchWords, string target)
{
    return searchWords.Any(word => target.ToLower()
         .Contains(word.ToLower()));
}
```

#### Edit

You also have to add a `using System.Linq;` :)

Comment: Looks like I can't use that `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` and I still get false

Comment: update example https://dotnetfiddle.net/QIXFDn

Comment: I see you are using .NET Framework, which doesn't support the `StringComparison` option.

Comment: For .NET Framework the easiest way is to convert both strings to lowercase before comparing them :)

Comment: your example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xb4Y3x